# how to display next set of paginated results on refresh of page using display tag in jsp

Tags: pagination, refresh, displaytag

I have used display tag library to show results from a list on my jsp page.
I have given pagesize as 12. I need to refresh the page results such that after a predefined interval my results are shown page by page 
i.e. at first load, page 1- 12 records seen, after interval, page 2- 12 records seen, ...etc.
Currently I am facing issue that every time my refresh happens I see only Page 1 results and thus my refresh will not allow me to see other pages.
Can anyone help me here please???

Comment: Please share the code you've used

Comment: Should be easy enough. How are you refreshing the page?